# select SUM in Cake

Tags: cakephp, select, sum

When I tried using follow code to get the sum of the column named `Serviceinfo.services`

```
$conditions = array('fields'=>array('SUM(Serviceinfo.services) as servicecount'),'conditions'=>array('time_id BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array($startid,$endtid)));
$services = $this->Serviceinfo->find('all',$conditions);
```

I had to fetch the sum data with `services[0][0]['servicecount']` which seems a little weird.And What I expect is `services['Serviceinfo']['servicecount']`,or more simple one.Then how can I fix this?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try it as:

```
'SUM(Serviceinfo.services) as Serviceinfo.servicecount'
```